# How to change active and hovering text in Javascript depending on condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these divs that I use as buttons.

```js
var color_switch = 1;
var tmbtns = document.getElementsByClassName("time-button");
    for (var i = 0; i < tmbtns.length; i++) {
      tmbtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active2");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active2", "");
        this.className += " active2";
      });
    }
```

```css
.time-buttons{
        float: left;
    }
    
    .time-button{
        float: left;
        padding: 0.2rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
        margin-left: 1px;
        margin-right: 1px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: lightgrey;
        width: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
        
    .active2, .time-button:hover{
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="time-buttons">
        <div class="time-button active2"><small>2h</small></div>
        <div class="time-button"><small>8h</small></div>
        <div class="time-button"><small>1d</small></div>
        <div class="time-button"><small>3d</small></div>
        <div class="time-button"><small>1w</small></div>
        <div class="time-button"><small>1m</small></div>
    </div>
```

How could I make it that when color_switch changes, the color that the text changes to also changes? So when color_switch = 1, the text is highlighted in red, and when color_switch = 2, the text is highlighted in blue, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use switch in which you'll set to what color should the current element be painted.

```
 switch (color_switch) {
  case 1:
    this.style.color = "red";
    break;

  case 2:
    this.style.color = "blue";
    break;
 }
```

There are many possible solutions, here is one of them: https://jsfiddle.net/9bj86L72/

Comment: Thanks alot! That's working for me

Comment: How do I add the functionality for hover? The hover pseudo-class cannot be changed so easily it seems

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to add/edit a hover effect in JavaScript without referring to CSS classes. So in this case, I suggest using Ricardo's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best practice is not merge css code in js, the best is create modifier classes and use it to map it in js. for example:

```
.time-buttons.type1 .time-button:hover {
  color: red;
}

.time-buttons.type2 .time-button:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

after in js according to de color_switch set the modifier class

```
document.querySelector('.time-buttons').className = document.querySelector('.time-buttons').className + " type" + color_switch
```

please view example in https://codepen.io/ricardocermeno/pen/ExojdVZ

Comment: Thank you! It is working nicely in your codepen, however I am having trouble getting it to work on my site. I will keep trying

Comment: I glad, please consider the selectors and modifier classes custom in your code.